# Add a search folder in all the mailboxes in the outlook 365 favourites

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I would like to have a search folder in the favorites which shows the content of all the inboxes.

If I search for `folder:Inbox` (or in my case `Ordner:Inbox` for German) in "All mailboxes" I get the desired result.

When I try to create a search folder I am forced to restrict it to one account.

Is there a way to store a search on all the accounts in the favourites?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the search folders in Outlook indeed have a mailbox level scope. For myself, I'm working with multiple search folders for different accounts and then add them to favourite now, which is inconvenient but effective. Or you could refer to these articles to get any other alternatives:

[Find All Unread Messages](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/find-all-unread-messages/)

[Unified Inbox folder for recent unread mail items](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/unified-inbox-for-recent-unread-mail-items)